# SQL Server query about joining 2 table with union

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `T1` and `T2`, both of them contain a column `ID` and `value`.

I need to join `T1` and `T2` into `T3` by means of `ID`.

`T3` should contain columns `ID`, `T1Value`, and `T2Value`.

The main requirement is, `ID` of `T1` and `T2` is possible not mapped

**T1**:

```
ID   VALUE
-----------
1    hi
2    hello
```

**T2**:

```
ID   VALUE
----------
2    kitty
3    dog
```

Then, `T3` should be

```
ID   T1VALUE   T2VALUE
----------------------
 1   hi
 2   hello     kitty
 3             dog
```

Is it possible to achieve this without using pivot table, or temp table (ideally should be a single executable query)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT ID      = COALESCE(T1.ID, T2.ID),
       T1VALUE = T1.VALUE,
       T2VALUE = T2.VALUE
FROM   T1
       FULL OUTER JOIN T2
       ON  T1.ID = T2.ID
```

There are lots of example on `FULL OUTER JOIN` . just search for it

Another way is to use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1VALUE = T1.VALUE, T2VALUE = NULL
FROM   T1

UNION ALL

SELECT T2.ID, T1VALUE = NULL,     T2VALUE = T2.VALUE
FROM   T2
```